# Assembly stiffness matrix for materials

Tags: matlab

I am working on fem elastic plane strain problem. I need to use 3 different materials now and I am having difficulties to do the assembly of stiffness matrix.

Here is a little cod of my assembly with one type of material:

```
edof = length(index);   % dof per element (x,y)

for i = 1:edof
    ii = index(i);

    for j = 1:edof
        jj = index(j);
        K(ii,jj) = K(ii,jj) + k(i,j);    % k elem stiffness matrix
    end

end
```

Suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use finite element method you first need to find a finite subspace V of the Hilbert-1 space (with compact support).

Let a be the differential operator of your problem. Then your stiffness matrix suffices:

`A(i,j) = a(phi(i),phi(j))`

where `phi(i)`and `phi(j)` are elements of V (your subspace).

With this [lecture notes](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/junge/NumPDE15/MA3303_Ch3.1.pdf) I learnt about FEM methods (page 23 will explain the above in more detail), here you will find more notes about [numerical PDEs](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/NumPDE1516/LectureNotes).

Hope this helps.